# dynamically add another component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a componentA (like a container) and what I'm trying to do is to add dynamically B components when a button is pressed. (I want to have a list of B components)

The following line helps me to add a B component (it works perfectly)

```
<div class="bclass" bDirective ></div>
```

But the problem is that I want to do this when the button is pressed. So I've tried the following function but it doesn't work.

```
        $scope.addBComponent = function(){

            var temp = document.createElement('div');
            temp.innerHTML = '<div class="bclass" bDirective ></div>';
            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(temp);
        };
```

Thanks,

Later edit:

bDirective is a directive that I've made who creates a square with some data in it. By pressind the add button I want to add that square. So, my problem is, how can I set one directive to a dynamically created div ?

Comment: Are you using Angularjs? How is the function called?

Comment: You need to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.addBComponent = function() {
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = '<div class="bclass" b-directive>dd</div>';
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(temp);
    $compile(temp)($scope);
  };
})

app.directive('bDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<span>This is a test content</span>'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <button ng-click="addBComponent()">Add</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Note: You should not do dom manipulation as done in `addBCompoment` in a controller, it should go to a directive if possible

Answer (score 1):

More HTML code would have been helpful but anyways.

I am assuming you want to append one more element(component) below div on click. Since your code looks like an angular JS script, I am answering it in angular

```
<div class="bclass" bDirective ng-bind-html="divHtmlVar"></div> 
<button ng-click="addBComponent ()">append</button>

  $scope.divHtmlVar = '<div>test html</div>';
  $scope.addBComponent = function(){
       $scope.divHtmlVar = $scope.divHtmlVar + '<div>New div</div>'; 
  };
```